# What is the difference between <index> and <map-key> elements of <map> element in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Any functional difference between those two. And please provide detail information.

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't find any noticeable difference, if you come to know  please share here.

Comment: @Zulfi You can? A search of https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/collections.html for `<index` turned up no hits. I have the same question.

Comment: Index was used in hibernate 2.x . From hibernate 3.x list-index is the element that is used to provide the index column. That's why you didn't find the index in latest docs. @Jason C

Comment: Huh. I don't think `list-index` works on maps. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_map_mapping.htm seems to use `index` where I'd expect `map-key`.